# How to remove the shutdown button from a Windows VM (on Azure)

Tags: azure, windows-server-2016

I have an a Windows 2016 VM on Azure that several users are RDPing into. The users are complaining that the VM shuts down at random times. When I check the logs, it shows that the shutdown has been initiated by the user! I would like to remove the option of shutting down the VM after RDPing into (remove the shutdown button). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the shutdown command, you can connect to the template VM and execute the below PowerShell script.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" -Name "HidePowerOptions" -Value 1 -Force
```

Or, you can choose to follow these manual steps using the template VM:

1.Press the Windows key, type gpedit, then select Edit group policy (Control panel).

2.Go to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar.

3.Right-click Remove and prevent access to the Shut Down, Restart, Sleep, and Hibernate commands, and click Edit.

4.Select the Enabled setting and then click OK:

5.Notice that the shutdown command no longer appears under Windows Start menu; only the Disconnect command appears.

Please refer link for detailed information :

[https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lab-services/how-to-windows-shutdown#:~:text=Press%20the%20Windows%20key%2C%20type,Hibernate%20commands%2C%20and%20click%20Edit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lab-services/how-to-windows-shutdown#:%7E:text=Press%20the%20Windows%20key%2C%20type,Hibernate%20commands%2C%20and%20click%20Edit).

Comment: IMHO, there are 2 ways, Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar > Remove and Prevent Access to the shutdown command. - this is the first, but does not prevent the using a command; the Second is,Computer Configuration > Windows Settings> Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Shut down the system.

This will defenitly even most advanced users prevent them from shutting it downhopefully